# What is the use of decorator sequences in deferred execution?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, decorator, lazy-evaluation

I am learning about LINQ, and  trying to understand, how deferred execution works?

The single line that is bothering me is :-

> Query operators provide deferred execution by returning **decorator sequences**.

I have tried searching about decorators, and the information I got was that:-

> Decorators attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically. Decorators provide a flexible alternative to subclassing for extending functionality.

I am not able to make any link b/w the execution of LINQ(Deferred execution) and the role of decorators there.

Therefore, I just want to know the role of decorator/decorator sequences in LINQ's deferred execution.

Comment: Where did you read that? It seems an odd description to me.

Comment: The first statement(about decorator sequences), was in `C# 5.0 in a nutshell`

Comment: With no further description of what's meant by "decorator sequences"? That's unusual - I generally rate C# 5 in a Nutshell pretty highly.

Answer (score 4):

That is a classic application of the [decorator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Let's "map" [the class diagram from wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aDecorator_UML_class_diagram.svg) to one of LINQ's methods with deferred execution below:

```
vat list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
var res = list.Take(3);
```

- `Component` is `IEnumerable<T>`
- `ConcreteComponent` is `List<T>`
- `ConcreteDecorator` is a class that implements `IEnumerable<T>` returned from the `Take(int)` method. The implementation has a reference to a `Component` (in our case, that's the `ConcreteComponent`, but it could be an abstract component as well).

Note, however, that the `ConcreteDecorator` is *not* (or not always) written manually. Instead, it is often [generated by the C# compiler](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx) when implementation uses a `yield return` statement.

Comment: How can they be an application of the decorator design pattern? Extension methods are static methods that are compiled in and are not changeable at runtime. 
The Decorator allows you to wrap a class inside another class and change its behavior (dynamically) -- something you couldn't do with a static extension method.

Comment: @snr The fact that LINQ methods are static is incidental. It's objects returned from them that are wrappers - I am talking about implementations of `IEnumerable<T>` returned from static LINQ methods: they wrap `IEnumerable<T>` objects passed into the method, and change their behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer for the actual terminology used, but the guts to understand is that LINQ to Objects is effectively implemented using iterator blocks (whether or not that's the actual implementation is somewhat irrelevant). So for example, ignoring argument validation, consider `Where`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                   Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    // TODO: Eager argument validation (not as easy as it sounds)
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

What's important is that this code only asks the original input source for its data when the sequence *returned* is asked for the next element. That's deferred execution for you. In fact, *none* of this method executes until the caller asks calls `GetEnumerator()` and then `MoveNext()`.

This is a decorator in that the returned sequence effectively ends up remembering a reference to the original sequence, and just performing a transformation on it as it goes along, rather than immediately fetching all the items.

For further information on this, see:

- My [article on iterator blocks and data pipelines](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx)
- My [article on iterator block implementation details](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx)
- [Part 2](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot.aspx) of my Edulinq blog series

Comment: How can they be an application of the decorator design pattern? Extension methods are static methods that are compiled in and are not changeable at runtime. The Decorator allows you to wrap a class inside another class and change its behavior (dynamically) -- something you couldn't do with a static extension method. However, I haven't started reading  https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot/. But, I have read https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Closures (:

Comment: @snr: Think of it as decorating `IEnumerable<T>`. Imagine an initial list of strings, then the returned sequence from `Where` - this has "decorated" the sequence by filtering out some of the elements. The original sequence is wrapped by the filtered sequence.